# Android 'N' level recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to have a recycler view in such a way -

```
Parent
-ParentItem
  Child1
  -Child1Item
     Child2
     -Child2Item
     .
     .
     .
     N
```

So the parent has an item and it has a child1. The child1 has an item and has a child2. The child2 has an item. This goes on..

How can I construct a recycler view for this?

Comment: You mean MulitView RecyclerView , array inside array?

Comment: @chandmohd Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[MultiView recyclerview](https://github.com/TakuSemba/MultiSnapRecyclerView)

Comment: But this is not supporting N level